# Getting HTTP status code from a jQueryui Autocomplete call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to get the response's HTTP status code from a jQuery UI Autocomplete call but I can't see any way to do so.

```
$( "#site_search" ).autocomplete({source: '/members/search/suggest',
                                  select: function (event, ui) {
                                              var search = escape(ui.item.value);
                                              window.location = '/members/search/?q='+search;
                                          },
                                  response: function (event, ui) {
                                              console.log ($(this));
                                              console.log (ui);
                                              console.log (event);
                                          }
});
```

The web site has a login that expires after a certain period of inactivity. However, if someone starts a search at that point, the auto-suggest just kind of takes a long time. What I'd like to do is read in the status code, see the 401 and then disable the auto-complete functionality for the page load.  I know how to do that part (the api has an enable/disable toggle), but I don't know how to get the status code back, even with putting the event and ui to the console.log.

Thanks,
Hans

**UPDATE**

Here's the final version that works under the several scenarios that were causing the problems. I'm very pleased. Thanks Amurra - big help.

```
// SITE SEARCH
if ($('input#site_search').length)
{
    $( "#site_search" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response)
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '/members/search/suggest',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        response(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        if (textStatus == 'timeout')
                        {
                            $('input#site_search').autocomplete('disable');
                        }
                        // Handle errors here
                    },
                    timeout: 2000, // the SBWS login can slow things down, too
                    statusCode:
                    {
                        401: function ()
                        {
                            $('input#site_search').autocomplete('disable');
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui)
            {
                var search = escape(ui.item.value);
                window.location = '/members/search/?q='+search;
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to define the source option and perform the submission yourself using [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Then handle the status codes you care about using the statusCode option:

```
$( "#site_search" ).autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response) {
       $.ajax({
         url: '/members/search/suggest',
         dataType: "json",
         data: { term: request.term },
         success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             response(data);
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           // Handle errors here 
         },
         statusCode: {
           401: function () {
             // Disable autocomplete here
           }
         }
    });
});,
```

Note: You will need jquery 1.5+ for this to work.

Comment: I never did report back until now and just FYI this worked like a charm. Thanks.